# Unbalanced processing of KeyedStream

Tags: apache-flink

I am facing a problem where KeyedStream is purely parallelised on workers
for case where number of keys is close to parallelism

My input records to  a range of 0-N。 When I use keyBy ， Some workers process zero keys, some more than one. This is because of `KeyGroupRangeAssignment.assignKeyToParallelOperator()` in `KeyGroupStreamPartitioner` use murmurHash to  the key.hasCode and select the channel。

I know the partitionCustom can handler this situation，but partitionCustom only return DataStream，not KeyStream。

So what can I do to handler without hack-ish？

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's kind of hack-ish, but see [makeKeyForOperatorIndex](https://github.com/ScaleUnlimited/flink-crawler/blob/master/src/main/java/com/scaleunlimited/flinkcrawler/utils/FlinkUtils.java#L153). I've used a custom `RichMapFunction` that figures out which subtask index it is in its `open()` call, and then uses `makeKeyForOperatorIndex` to create a key (Integer or String) that is added as a field and then used for the `keyBy()`.

Comment: thanks for the support， I have same problem for the makeKeyForOperatorIndex。 1. for the parameter operatorIndex ， is 0- N （parallelism） ？ 2. what situation would happend unable to find for target operator index ？ 3.  I use  0-3，parallelism is 3. the console out     3> (9 ,1)   3 > (0, 2)  1> (4,0)    。 I think the result should be  1> (9 ,1)   2 > (0, 2)  0> (4,0)   .   Did I do some wrong with the method？

Answer (score 0):

It's unfortunately a bit burried, but there is a way of turning a `DataStream` into a `KeyedStream`.

```
DataStream<T> partitioned = input.partitionCustom(...);
KeyedStream<T> keyed = DataStreamUtils.reinterpretAsKeyedStream(partitioned, ...)
```